# Undeclared idenitifier

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Need help with this. I am using version 4 of pinescript.

The objective is to get this script to look at 4 days of candles.

I added "red_candle_3_days_ago and " and there was no errors.

Then when I add to this script the following line - "open_2_day_ago >= close_3_days_ago and" an error happened. See below.

I get a Undeclared identifier - why does this happening?

```
//Bearish Reversal pattern with 79% success in Bear markets and 78% in Bull markets
FOUR_Black_Crows = (red_candle_3_days_ago and red_candle_2_days_ago and red_candle_1_day_ago and red_candle_today)  
 and (open_2_day_ago >= close_3_days_ago and open_1_day_ago >= close_2_days_ago and open_today >= close_1_day_ago)  
 and (open_2_days_ago >= high_1_day_ago and open_1_day_ago >= high_today)  
 and (low_2_days_ago >= close_1_day_ago and low_1_day_ago >= close_today)
```

Then I also attempted to add this as a separate line item due to the error above -

"and (open_2_day_ago >= close_3_days_ago and open_today >= close_1_day_ago)"

Again I get the same Undeclared identifier message- all I did was add a line and change the numbers.

What am I not understanding about pinescript?

Regards

Comment: "Undeclared identifier" means one of the variables you're using wasn't declared above/previously.
Try executing one out of the 4 lines only, then if it works executes 2 lines, then 3, and so on and so forth until you pinpoint which variable hasn't been declared above

Comment: Show us the exact error message and your whole code.

Comment: I have worked out the issue with a friend. Thank you for your input.